# getting a shared libavfilter.so.0 error when encoding a video using ffmpeeg

Tags: ffmpeg

When trying to encode a wmv to flv.. I am facing this error

> /home/radiorac/public_html/video/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavfilter.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any suggestions, I've did some looking but could not find any specific information on that error.. Any suggestions would be greatful!

Comment: Your question should be posted on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: pinichi is right, though I will admit that I didn't know that either until I looked at the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the libavfilter package. On Ubuntu systems this should just be...

`sudo apt-get install libavfilter0`

There could be more wrong but this is the solution 90% of the time.